# JPA Dates not getting formatted

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java.util.date

I have a html form with a date time picker for submitting and retrieving dates to my Springboot entity and into my MySQL database.

We use dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm format in this part of the world.

Submission of dates works fine. When I try to retrieve a date nothing is shown in the form.

The html looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="start_date" th:text="${#start_date}" />
```

The java entity looks like:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Episode {

protected Episode() {}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
...
@Column(name="start_date")
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
private Date start_date;
```

The actual value stored in the database looks like:

```
2017-01-25 18:01:23
```

I would have expected the pattern in the entity would handle this, but clearly I am missing something.

I also tried getting thymeleaf to do the formatting with:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="start_date" th:text="${#dates.format(start_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')}" />
```

But that is invalid thymeleaf.

How to retreive the date correctly - preferably in backend (java).

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your thymeleaf html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="start_date" th:value="${{episode.start_date}}" />
```

1. Use th:value instead of th:text
2. start_date is a seperate entity with a relationship to episode so the thymeleaf object reference is episode.start_date

The entity does not need to be modified.

You also need to use double braces like "{{"

Refer http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#double-brace-syntax